# Flask babel not workinf since revamped project with blueprints

Tags: python, flask, internationalization, flask-babel

I have an app working well and translating with flask babel.

Then, I started to split the code in modules and generating blueprints instead of still writing all code inside the same .py file.

This is my project structure:

[image: Project structure]

Then, this is the code from main file: FinMapper.py

```
from app import create_app

app = create_app('default')
```

Code of app/**init**.py

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_babel import Babel
from config import config


def register_blueprints(app):
    from .file_import import file_import_blueprint
    app.register_blueprint(file_import_blueprint)


def get_locale():
    return 'es'


babel = Babel()


def create_app(config_name):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(config[config_name])
    config[config_name].init_app(app)
    register_blueprints(app)
    babel.init_app(app)

    return app
```

Code on forms.py:

```
class MovementFileForm(FlaskForm):
    type = SelectField(lazy_gettext('Type'), choices=[('default', 'DEFAULT'), ('bbva', 'BBVA')])
    file = FileField(lazy_gettext('File'),
                     validators=[DataRequired(),
                                 FileAllowed(['csv'], message='FileExtensionNotAllowed')],
                     render_kw={"class": "form-control"})
```

The calls to lazy_gettext('text') was working until refactoring to create blueprints.

And here an example of base.html with the navbar:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><b>FinMapper</b></a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
                aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">{{ _('Dashboard') }}</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">{{ _('Categories') }}</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">{{ _('Categorize') }}</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="{{ url_for('file_import_blueprint.load') }}">{{ _('Load') }}</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Like lazy_gettext, the call of method _('text') was working until create blueprints.

My main doubt is if this code in the app factory is correct, I think that here is the problem:

[image: Babel declaration detail]

This is the first version of the code, working well without blueprints:

[image: Project vanilla no blueprints]

I don't know how must be instantiated or declared Babel to be able to use in all blueprints. Now, my translations are not working.

## Update

I'm able to call locale selector, but still without translations. If I configure babel like this:

```
babel = babel()

def create_app(config_name):
    app = Flask(__name)
    babel.init(app, locale_selector=gel_locale()
    # more coding
```

Putting a print inside get_locale function, it works, is being called. But translations still not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved moving translations folder inside app.

You can see the 1st photo uploaded with old project estructure.

Now, this is the new project structure:

[image: New project structure]

Answer (score 0):

### Short answer :

You referenced a call of your function, not the function itself.

And you probably did a typo on `init_app`.

Please change :

```py
babel.init(app, locale_selector=gel_locale())
```

to

```py
babel.init_app(app, locale_selector=gel_locale)
```

### Explanations

If you're using Flask-Babel 4.0.x, the @localeselector decorator doesn't exist anymore and you should reference a function as a localselector argument when creating your babel instance.

However, if you're using the app factory pattern (creating your app in a function and not directly in the file), you should declare the local_selector function in your init_app and not in your Babel instanciation.

Eg :

```py
from flask import Flask
from flask_babel import Babel
from config import my_config

babel = Babel()

def get_locale():
    # put your code to manage your user favorite language here
    # I recommend using flask session in order to maintain persistence between requests 

    return "en"

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(my_config)
    babel.init_app(app, locale_selector=get_locale)
    
    return app
```